# WebView goBackMethod takes me out of web view fragment

Tags: android, webview

I am using a webview inside fragment.I want to implement onBackPress on the fragment, so that the app goes from one link back to previous link.This is my following code

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 //   super.onBackPressed();
    if(webView!=null && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I have implemented this inside the fragment via base fragment.If I open multiple links inside the webview, it goes to the code

> webView.goBack()

But rather than going back to previous page it takes me out of the fragment.
Why is it happening so.?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the below code in the back button implementation

```
    switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.imag_back:
                if (webview.canGoBack()) {
                    webview.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
}
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Also please check your parent activity for onbackpressed() method

Comment: It is executing the code webView.goBack(),and after that it is going out.

Comment: You also have to check the onback implementation in the  main activity

Answer (score 0):

Use ChildFragmentManager and put your webView Urls into it.

In your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, WebFragment.newInstance(), "WEB_FRAGMENT_TAG")
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        WebFragment fragment = (WebFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WEB_FRAGMENT_TAG");
        int stackEntryCount = fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (stackEntryCount > 0) {
            fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            fragment.popUrlBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

In your Fragment

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(url).commit();
            }
        });
    }

    public void popUrlBack() {
        webView.goBack();
    }
```